# Class not Found for HttpUriRequest

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to make a Jar file to be used to connect to a rest service I have written in Node.js. I was following this guide to do so.

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/

After compiling with Maven it gives this error:

```
 Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

***App.java***

```
package com.vogella.build.maven.java;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
            "http://localhost:3001/getTestData");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }

}
```

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.vogella.build.maven.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.vogella.build.maven.java</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>com.vogella.build.maven.java</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Would anybody know whats going wrong with this?

Comment: can you try removing the `httpclient` jar from your /m2/repository once, updating to the  `<version>4.5.3</version>` and building the project again (`mvn clean install`)

Comment: @nullpointer I dont have a httpclient jar. I thought Maven would just get that for me? Do I need to do additional steps to get Maven to download that jar file?

Answer (score 1):

Your application depends on httpclient-4.1.1.jar , you need to run your application by having the jar in classpath. Maven downloads the jar into your local repository when you build the application.

You can find lot of example on how to specify classpath, [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495893/running-a-java-program-at-the-command-line-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

[Running a java program at the command line, what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495893/running-a-java-program-at-the-command-line-what-am-i-doing-wrong)